# Store user authorized in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router, firebase-authentication, react-redux

I'm looking for a way, when a user authorized, I store `user authorized status` so every time I can check if the user is `authorized` or not. However, when I execute the following code user is not authorized: (Master.jsx -> render())

```
<Route exact path="/" render={() => {
  console.log('this.props.authed: ', this.props.authed, "this.props: ", this.props)
  return (
  this.props.authed
  ? <Home />
  : <Redirect from="/" to="/login"/>
)}
}/>
```

I check user authorization via `firebase` in `componentWillMount()` and store it the following code:(Master.jsx -> componentWillMount())

```
componentWillMount = () => {

  firebaseAuth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {

        if (user) {
        this.props.login(user)
        } else {
         this.props.logout()
        }
      })
}
```

The problem is that will `componentWillMount` will be executed after `<Route ..` so the user will be authorized after `routing`. I there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic use case of react-redux. I would recommend all the authentications to be handled at the server side where server responds with true or false for authorized or unauthorized user. Until this happens you can show a loading icon on the UI.

But, incase you want to go ahead and want to authenticate user on the UI, look into react-redux.

Essentially you will have to do this

**When user logs in**

1. Dispatch a logIn action in your action.js
2. Catch the logIn action in your reduce.js and store the user credentials in the store

**When user reloads/ opens the page**

1. Dispatch a isLoggedIn action in your action.js
2. Reduce isLoggedIn action and check if the user already exits in the state. If yes, return allow the program to proceed. If no, ask user to log in again.

Hope that helps!

Comment: If you see my question the problem is that my storing processor will be executed after the `react-router` is called. So before I store the user data in the redux store that user is authorized `react-router` redirect to another page!